# is '__all__' only for 'from some import *'

Tags: python

a.py

```
__all__=['b','c']
a='aaa'
b='bbb'
def c():
    print 'ccc'
def d():
    print 'dddd'
```

b.py

```
from a import a
print a
from a import *
print a
print d#error
```

Are there any other uses.

thanks

Comment: see this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it also changes what help(a) documents.

Answer (score 0):

No, the purpose of `__all__` is just to describe exactly what should be imported when you do `from foo import *`.

Answer (score 0):

No other uses, except limiting the damage caused by the horrible `from ... import *` usage.

Comment: In defense of "import *": `from math import *` is arguably reasonable, when one manipulates lots of mathematical formulas.